# sum of exponential series with power increasing by geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-function, exponential-sum, geometric-series

Is there any way to reduce the following summation... $2^{ar^0}+2^{ar^1}....+ 2^{ar^n} $ to a simple equation?

I feel like I can pull out a $2^a$ somehow and then treat it as a normal series but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Even if the exponent-of-the-exponent would be a simple constant, other than $0$ or $1$, the series you've written is not known to possess a closed form. See [Jacobi elliptic $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), for instance.